# get a list of active or re-running apps in android

Tags: android, proc, terminate

I want to get a list of active or re-running apps in android
to be able for user to terminate from the list shown on the screen
but maybe something has gone wrong because when I touch refresh button no new apps are shown

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    runningAppsList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, runningAppsList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    // Refresh the app list every hour
    listView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateRunningAppsList();
            listView.postDelayed(this, 3600000);
        }
    }, 3600000);

    // Select all apps when the "Select All" button is clicked
    Button selectAllButton = findViewById(R.id.select_all_button);
    selectAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int count = adapter.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                listView.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All apps selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Kill the selected apps when the "Kill" button is clicked
    Button killButton = findViewById(R.id.kill_button);
    killButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int count = adapter.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
                    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(adapter.getItem(i).packageName);
                }
            }
            // Wait for 1 second to let the terminated apps get removed from the running apps list
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateRunningAppsList();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });


    // Start the service that monitors terminated apps
    appTerminatedService = new AppTerminatedService();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppTerminatedService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

private void updateRunningAppsList() {
    runningAppsList.clear();
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> allAppsList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : allAppsList) {
        if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
            runningAppsList.add(appInfo);
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class AppTerminatedService extends Service {
    private ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo mProcessInfo;
    private ArrayList<String> mRunningApps;
    private PackageManager mPackageManager;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private boolean mIsTerminated = false;
    private Runnable mUpdateApps = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateRunningApps();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    public AppTerminatedService() {
        mRunningApps = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateApps, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void updateRunningApps() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

        // Get the list of running processes
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcessList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        // Add the names of all running apps to a list
        ArrayList<String> runningApps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcessList) {
            String appName = "";
            try {
                appName = mPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(mPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(processInfo.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)).toString();
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runningApps.add(appName);
        }

        // Check if any apps have been terminated
        if (mIsTerminated) {
            ArrayList<String> terminatedApps = new ArrayList<>(mRunningApps);
            terminatedApps.removeAll(runningApps);

            // Remove the terminated apps from the running apps list
            for (String app : terminatedApps) {
                mRunningApps.remove(app);
            }
            mIsTerminated = false;
        }

        // Update the running apps list
        for (String app : runningApps) {
            if (!mRunningApps.contains(app)) {
                mRunningApps.add(app);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        mIsTerminated = true;
    }
}
```

}

I only got my app name in the list and laucher but no more other
what is right method to get list of all installed and apps which can be in rerun state